# model.predict classes don't match dataset classes

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm writing a CNN classifier, using Keras, that it supposed to classify a set of 40k+ pictures of road signs to one of 43 classes. Everything is fine until I try to find out what mistakes the model has made while classifying unseen data. It appears that the classes in the output file are mismatched to the classes from the dataset, and I don't know how to determine which class is which. The problem is better explained at the end of the question.

The batch size is 64. The output file is very large, but it has a structure as follows:

```
[[3.81430182e-05 3.55855487e-02 3.77756208e-02 ... 3.93179851e-03 4.57952236e-04 1.19631949e-07]
[2.46175125e-09 8.71188703e-08 9.04489157e-12 ... 7.63094476e-08 2.24849509e-06 9.93708588e-13]
...
[1.31991830e-13 1.99924495e-12 7.65954244e-10 ... 1.51650678e-13 1.77550303e-14 9.25261628e-16]]
-
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
...
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

This is the output for one batch, there are 198 such batches in total. First there are 64 rows with 43 values each representing the output of the neural network. Then there are 64 rows with 43 values each, that represent which class is the correct classification.

In the test set, the classes are denoted by a folder structure as follows:

```
Test_New/0
    00245.png
    00252.png
    00403.png
   ...
Test_New/1
    00001.png
    00024.png
    00076.png
   ...
...
Test_New/42
    00315.png
    00507.png
    00755.png
    ...
```

The problem is, that the classes from the file don't match up with the classes from the output file! In other words, I would expect that this in the output file:

```
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

Would mean that the correct classification for this particular image was the third class, because the 1 is in the 3rd spot. But this is not the case. How do I know? Because I know that there are exactly 750 files in the "Test_New/2" folder which represents the third class, but when I use the find function in notepad++ to find all instances of the

```
[0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
```

line, it returns a number of 660. That means that there are 660 instances of this line in the file, and that means that it cannot represent the third class. In fact, it represents the 11th class because it's the only one with this many files in it. This wouldn't be a problem if all the folders had a different number of files, but unfortunately some of them share the same number of files.

My question is why are the output classes shuffled in the output file, and how do I fix this? How do I know which class is which? If you don't know, do you know if there is a different way to know which images were wrongly classified? Please help, I've been pulling my hair out for the last 3 hours or so. I'm sorry that there is so much code, I just don't know where the error is. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In your test and validation generators set shuffle-False.
In model.fit do not specify steps_per_epoch or validation_steps let model.fit determine these values internally. Now one of the things you must remember is that python functions like flow_from_directory process the filenames in alphanumeric order. So if for example you have files in a directory labelled 1.jpg, 2.jpg ----9.jpg, 10,jpg ---- the order the files are processed  in is 1.jpg, 10.jpg, 11.jpg-----19.jpg, 2.jpg ---. So if you expect the order to be strictly numerical it is not. Below is the code for a function that will detect misclassified test files and print out the file names, true class, predicted class and the probability of the prediction for all misclassified test files.

```
def print_info( test_dir, test_gen, preds, print_code ):
    # test_dir is the full path to the directory containing the test images
    # test_gen is the name of your test generator
    # preds are the prediction from preds=model.predict
    # print code is an integer specifying the maximum number of error files you want to print out
    class_dict=test_gen.class_indices
    labels= test_gen.labels
    file_names= test_gen.filenames 
    error_list=[]
    true_class=[]
    pred_class=[]
    prob_list=[]
    new_dict={}
    error_indices=[]
    y_pred=[]
    for key,value in class_dict.items():
        new_dict[value]=key             # dictionary {integer of class number: string of class name}
    classes=list(new_dict.values())     # list of string of class names
    errors=0    
    for i, p in enumerate(preds):
        pred_index=np.argmax(p)
        true_index=labels[i]  # labels are integer values
        if pred_index != true_index: # a misclassification has occurred
            error_list.append(file_names[i])
            true_class.append(new_dict[true_index])
            pred_class.append(new_dict[pred_index])
            prob_list.append(p[pred_index])
            error_indices.append(true_index)            
            errors=errors + 1
        y_pred.append(pred_index)   
    if print_code !=0:
        if errors>0:
            if print_code>errors:
                r=errors
            else:
                r=print_code           
            msg='{0:^28s}{1:^28s}{2:^28s}{3:^16s}'.format('Filename', 'Predicted Class' , 'True Class', 'Probability')
            print(msg)
            for i in range(r):
                msg='{0:^28s}{1:^28s}{2:^28s}{3:4s}{4:^6.4f}'.format(error_list[i], pred_class[i],true_class[i], ' ', prob_list[i])
                print(msg)
                            
        else:
            msg='With accuracy of 100 % there are no errors to print'
            print(msg)
```